# json parsing in javascript with dynamic key in loop

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my json format

```
dropdownvalues":[{"ddv0":"57###Cool White###0###","ddv1":"59###Warm White###0###"}]}]
```

i want to parse ddv0,ddv1,ddv2...so on.

`alert(dropdownvalues[j].ddv0);`// That is working fine

But I want to parse like

```
for( var i=0;i<=obj.length;i++)    
{    
   var key="ddv"+i;    
   alert(dropdownvalues[].key); // That is giving undefined    
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a `for...in` statement? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

```
for( var i=0;i<=obj.length;i++)    
{    
   var key="ddv"+i;    
   alert(dropdownvalues[i].key); // include index in array to choose object   
}
```

Adding explanation from my comment below:

An array is an indexed list of items (in this case objects). In order to access the item at index `i` you need to pass the index into the array - `dropdownvalues[i]`.

Comment: Some explanation of what this does and how would be helpful.

Comment: An array is an indexed list of items (in this case objects). In order to access the item at index `i` you need to pass the index into the array, this `dropdownvalues[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the associative array notation:

```
var key = 'ddv' + j;
alert(dropdownvalues[j][key]);
```